# login page in content place holder

Tags: asp.net

(web app)
 I have a login page and a home page both having different master pages
I want to display login page in content place holder of home page.is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can host the Login Control not an .ASPX.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do that if your login part is a user control then you can include it in your home page.

Answer (score 0):

i would say..you can change the contentplaceholder's id in the source of the login page. this may help..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you can do so using iframe,
in the content place holder of the home page , put

`<iframe id="loginIframe" src="login.aspx" />`